# PHP Send file in HTML form to mail

Tags: php, html, file, email, join

i want the send 2 files attached to  an email by using an html form. The mail is send with the 2 files but I can't see the files when i download (size: 0 ko). 
Cant you help me please? Here is the code of my php file:

```
$boundary = "-----=".md5(uniqid(rand()));

$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$header .= "\r\n";

$msg = "Je vous informe que ceci est un message au format MIME 1.0 multipart/mixed.\r\n";

$msg .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n";
$msg .= "Ceci est un mail avec 2 fichiers joints\r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n";

$file = $_FILES['icone']['name'];
$fp   = fopen($file, "rb");   // le b c'est pour les windowsiens
$attachment = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment));

$msg .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"$file\"\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"\r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n";
$msg .= $attachment . "\r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n\r\n";

$file = $_FILES['nom_fichier']['name'];
$fp = fopen($file, "rb");
$attachment = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment));

$msg .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"$file\"\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"\r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n";
$msg .= $attachment . "\r\n";
$msg .= "\r\n\r\n";

$msg .= "--$boundary--\r\n";

$destinataire = "jeanb@hotmail.com";
$expediteur   = $_POST['email'];
$reponse      = $expediteur;
echo "Ce script envoie un mail avec 2 fichiers joints à $destinataire";
mail($destinataire,
     "Email avec 2 fichiers joints (dont 1 inline)",
     $msg,
     "Reply-to: $reponse\r\nFrom: $destinataire\r\n".$header);
```

The warning message is:

> Warning: fopen(date horloge.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/public_html/mail_candidat.php on line 34
>
> Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for date
>   horloge.txt in /home/public_html/mail_candidat.php on line 35
>
> Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
>   /home/public_html/mail_candidat.php on line 35
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
>   in /home/public_html/mail_candidat.php on line 36

Ce script envoie un mail avec 2 fichiers joints à jeanb@hotmail.com

Comment: Do use english in your question. ich antworte ja auch nicht auf deutsch.

Comment: Well, the error message clearly tells you that you are trying to open and to read from a file that does not exist. You path points to no file. Most likely this is a _path_ issue here. What is your _current working directory_?

Comment: I want users to upload files, that i while received directly in my email. I don't have a "current working directory"... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The path to the file is stored in 'tmp_name' and not in name. Name how the file is called but not the path to the file.

in your example that would be.

**Before**

```
$file = $_FILES['nom_fichier']['name'];
$fp = fopen($file, "rb");
$attachment = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
```

**After**

```
$file = $_FILES['nom_fichier']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($file, "rb");
$attachment = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i've done it but i receive an empty file again (file size 0 ko). Do you now this issue?

Comment: can you show the html form that you use when posting to this script?

Comment: Here is the form
<form method="post" action="mail_candidat.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="icone" id="icone" />

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />

<input type="file" name="mon_fichier" id="mon_fichier" />

<input type="text" name="nom" value="Nom & Prénoms" id="nomprenom" />

<input type="text" name="email" value="Email" id="email" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" />

Answer (score 0):

*fopen* cannot find the file (*No such file or directory*). 
All the other warnings are related to that.

Check the path returned and see if It returns a valid path.

Comment: I want to send the files directly from the html form to email, by my php file. I don't know how to check the path (valid or not). Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have a working directory (That is a directory where is your php file) in this case this is : /home/public_html/ but you have to know did you have a permisson to upload a file to this directory, or you have a tmp or any other writeable directory.

Extend your code like this:

```
$file =  basename($_FILES['icone']['name']);
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['icone']['tmp_name'], $file)) {    echo "Error";} 
echo "file: ".$file; //For debug only
$fp = fopen($file, "rb");
$attachment = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
echo $attachment; //For debug only
```

If it is not work, please comment the warning or error message.

As I see you didnt uploaded a File.

Your error is said same "ailed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/public_html/mail_candidat.php"

Try to upload file before sending it:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php